# Updating global var before a function executes

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I have a code with this structure

```
var no_data=false;

function checkdata(){
   //reset of the global var
   no_data=false
   //some code that return an array, called data
   if(data.length==0) no_data=true;

}
```

Then I execute the function checkdata() and check the var no_data to do an alert if it's true, but It updates late, in the second time I call it :S

And I tried to return in the function the errors, like no data etc, but It wont work :S

Maybe is a problem of compatibility of global scope with the livequery jquery plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update `no_data` before execution of function `checkdata`.
then update it just before call of function `checkdata` .

```
no_data=false;
checkdata();
```